# Quadratic equation can be written in the form...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, quadratic-forms

$y = 2x^2 + 5x - 3$ can be written in the form $y = 2(x+a)^2 + b$ . Find the value of $a$ and the value of $b$.

Edit: Answers were $a= 1.25, b= -6.125$.
I dont understand how that's the answer.

Comment: See [completing the square](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand 
\begin{align}
(x+a)^2 &= x^2+2ax + a^2\\
\implies 2(x+a)^2 +b &= 2x^2+4ax+2a^2+b
\end{align}
Which allows for
\begin{align}
4a&= 5\\
2a^2 +b &= -3
\end{align}
Now solve for $(a, b)$.

Comment: 4a = 5 and 2a^2 + b = -3. I dont understand this part :(

Comment: @Zamir If $2x^2+4x-3 = 2(x+a)^2+b$ is true for all $x$, then the coefficients of the $x^2$ terms are equal to one anotehr, as are the terms in $x$ and the constants mucst match up. I wrote that the coeficicents of $x$ are in equal in the first line ($4a=5)$ and then the constants must be equal so that $2a^2+b = -3$. once you solve for $a$, you can plug this into the second relation to find $b$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x^2+5x-3=2\left(x^2+2x\cdot\frac{5}{4}+\frac{25}{16}-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{25}{16}\right)=$$
$$=2\left(x+\frac{5}{4}\right)^2-\frac{49}{8}.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. What are those fractions 5/4 + 25/16 − 3/2 − 25/16 and how did you get them?